# Use a dynamic Activity name while calling it's method from a fragment

Tags: android

Ok, so I've a Fragment inside which I use `getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName()` to get the name of the activity that contains it.
Now, I've a method called `sampleMethod()` inside that activity, and to call it from the fragment I use `((MyActivity) getActivity()).sampleMethod();` This works fine as well.

My question is that how can I use the activity name in the statement `((MyActivity) getActivity()).sampleMethod();` dynamically. Obviously, I do get the name from `getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName()`. 
So what I want is something like

```
`((getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName()) getActivity()).sampleMethod();
```

Syntactically, the above is incorrect. What's the correct way?

Comment: i think getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName() this will return the name string of activity.

Comment: "What's the correct way?" - Use an `interface` to interact with the hosting `Activity`. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Activities that include this fragment should implement an interface, let's say

```
interface Sample {
   public void sampleMethod();
}
```

then in your fragment

```
((Sample)getActivity()).sampleMethod();
```